# How do you calculate the proportion of shares required to formulate a minimum risk portfolio?

Tags: investing, stock-analysis, starting-out-investing, portfolio, value-investing

An investor has decided to invest 1 million in the shares of two companies, company E and company B. the projections of returns from the shares of the two companies along with their probabilities is shown below. Required; Determine the proportion of each shares required to formulate a minimum risk portfolio.

```
probability  :  company E  :  Company B
   0.20      :     12      :     16
   0.25      :     14      :     10
   0.25      :     -7      :     28
   0.30      :     28      :     -2
```

I used the approach of variance. From my insights i weighted the variances and got company E could weight 0.4241 and company B 0.5758. I am however not sure of the approach

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because you should be doing your own homework. If you edit to say what you think the right answer is, someone might be willing to check your work.

Comment: Well this is not homework sir/madam. I am preparing for my Finance exam. I used the approach of variance. From my insights i weighted the variances and got company E could weight 0.4241 and company B 0.5758. I am however not sure of the approach

Comment: I'm sorry, but you used the term "minimum risk portfolio" right after saying that someone who is *starting-out-investing* was going to invest a substantial sum of money in only 2 stocks.  Share investing carries inherent risks.  Cash in the bank does not.  So for a minimum risk strategy, (1) don't invest in shares, and (2) if you really must invest in shares then spread your investment across a range of stocks covering a range of industries.

Comment: Oh yes " minimum risk portfolio," in the context of the question.

Comment: Yeah, the question is somewhat self-negating . Whatever you calculate will still be bad advice. If I got this question, phrased this way, my answer would be "mu"

Comment: @keshlam I think it would be better stated as "Assume you're investing in these 2 companies, what proportion minimizes the risk?"

Comment: @GregSchmidt you appear to not be familiar with finance. That's like if someone asks "What's the minimum fencing that a farmer can use in this situation?" and you respond "If the farmer just lets their animals be free-range, they can use no fencing at all." Also, money in a bank is absolutely not risk-free. Inflation is a rather considerable risk.

Comment: @keshlam 1. You don't seem to understand what "self-negating means". 2. The question isn't asking for advice. It's asking to calculate a well-defined finance concept.

Comment: @Barmar The question says "An investor has decided to invest 1 million in the shares of two companies". Given that, and just being familiar with the concept of minimizing risk given a set of securities, it's clear that it is to be assumed that all the money is to be invested in the two companies.

Comment: @Acccumulation Yes, but kesham effectively answered "Should I invest 1 million in these two companies?" I think the context should be that they've already done the research and decided that this is a reasonable place to start, and now they just want to know the best proportion. "Mu" is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Referring back to [old notes](http://www.cwgsy.net/private/degnen/investing/theory.html) this looks ok.  `r` is the mean return, `x` & `y` are the proportions of E & B respectively, `s` is the risk

```
r = 0.20*(0.12 x + 0.16 y) +
    0.25*(0.14 x + 0.10 y) +
    0.25*(-0.07 x + 0.28 y) +
    0.30*(0.28 x - 0.02 y)

s = (0.20*(0.12 x + 0.16 y - r)^2 +
     0.25*(0.14 x + 0.10 y - r)^2 +
     0.25*(-0.07 x + 0.28 y - r)^2 +
     0.30*(0.28 x - 0.02 y - r)^2)^(1/2)

y = 1 - x
```

Plotting `s` over a range of `x` from 0 to 1 the minimum risk is about 46.5% E and 53.5% B.

[image]